# pymysql insert on duplicate key update. Problem with tuple on update

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

My idea is to insert dinamically dataframe data into a mysql table without using sqllchemy ORM, so am trying to insert the following sql expression in a table:

```
sql="INSERT INTO database.table("+str(str_of_cols) +") VALUES ("+str(str_of_vals)+") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "+str(str_of_updt)
connector.execute(sql,insert_values,update_values)
```

Where:
**str_of_cols** is a string like: id_ticket,cola_destino,fecha_creacion,fecha_modificacion,fecha_cierre,severidad,last_update
**str_of_vals** is a string like:  %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s
**str_of_updt** is another string: cola_destino=%s,last_update=%s
**insert_values** is a tuple: ('111615379', 'movil_quality', '2021-03-18 13:49:06', '2022-09-02 09:35:44', None, '3', '2022-09-03 13:54:36')
**update_values** is another tuple:  ('movil_quality', '2022-09-03 13:54:36')

The SQL print returns:

```
INSERT INTO vision_db.aeim_tir_padre (id_ticket,cola_destino,fecha_creacion,fecha_modificacion,fecha_cierre,severidad,last_update) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cola_destino=%s,last_update=%s
```

But the execution returns the error "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

If I only insert the values, the execution goes well, the issue is with the update. I don't know how to unpack the tuple "update_values= ('movil_quality', '2022-09-03 13:54:36')" to fit in "cola_destino=%s,last_update=%s", so:
cola_destino='movil_quality' and last_update='movil_quality'

any clue? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass one tuple with all values as one parameter

```py
connector.execute(sql,(*insert_values, *update_values))
```